# Python : different regular expressions with different substitutions

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I have a couple of different regular expressions to be matched and substitued in a given text.

- regex1 : if the text contains the word "founder", replace all text by
  CEO
- regex 2 : if the text contains 9 digit number  , replace it with
  NUM

I am trying to do this with combined regex as follows:

```
regex = re.compile(r'((.*)founder(.*)|^[0-9]{4}$')
```

The issue is that when applying substitution on regex , i need to know which of the combined pattern is matched to use the corresponding substitution.

I'd be grateful if somone can help me to implement this !

Comment: please give some examples

Comment: Do you want to combine two completely independent regexes into one? Why? It's bound to be a lot slower and more error prone than simply running each regex substitution in sequence.

Comment: You could call re.match before executing re.sub

Comment: Actually i have to apply these substitutions to a column of csv file that contains a high number of rows . So i want to do this in one pass for a given row ... also the regex number is not 2 but more than 20 ... so i cant do it individually for each regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """ if the text contains the word founder
123456789 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf"""

text = re.sub("founder", "CEO", s)
text = re.sub("[0-9]{9}", "NUM", text)  

print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
 if the text contains the word CEO
NUM sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf
```

Comment: He also wants to know which substitution was executed. I guess adding a re.match before each re.sub would work.

Comment: Actually i have to apply these substitutions to a column of csv file that contains a high number of rows . So i want to do this in one pass for a given row ... also the regex number is not 2 but more than 20 ... so i cant do it individually for each regex

Comment: @Rakesh Actually i have to apply these substitutions to a column of csv file that contains a high number of rows . So i want to do this in one pass for a given row ... also the number of regex  is not 2 but more than 20 ( i gave 2 just for example) ... so i cant do it individually for each regex

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can easily avoid regex here:

```
def replace_em(text):
    if 'founder' in text:                   # if text contains founder
        return 'CEO'
    elif text.isdigit() and len(text) == 9: # all digits and length = 9
        return 'NUM'
    else:
        return text

print(replace_em("Some founder here")) # CEO
print(replace_em("123456789"))         # NUM
print(replace_em("Some other text"))   # Some other text
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1fL5TR).

If you want to play around with regex and `re.sub` you may try using this code, but mind it is less efficient:

```
import re

def replace_em(m):
    return 'NUM' if m.group(1) else 'CEO'

regex = re.compile(r'(?s)^([0-9]{9})$|.*founder.*')

print(re.sub(regex, replace_em, "Some founder here"))
print(re.sub(regex, replace_em, "123456789"))
print(re.sub(regex, replace_em, "Some other text"))
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/LFAZ8S)

Here, `(?s).*founder.*|^([0-9]{9})$` matches any string having `founder` in it with the first alternative (mind the `(?s)` makes `.` match any char including line break chars) and another alternative matches and *captures* into Group 1 a nine-digit string. The second argument is a callback method that replaces the matches based on custom logic (if Group 1 matched, replace with `NUM` else, with `CEO`).

Comment: Actually i have to apply these substitutions to a column of csv file that contains a high number of rows . So i want to do this in one pass for a given row ... also the regex number is not 2 but more than 20 ... so i cant do it individually for each regex

Comment: @lyesAlgerian Then you will still have to use some sort of a callback method since `re` does not support string conditional replacement. See my snippet and tailor for your specific needs.